# Получить количество элементов при выборе checkbox WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть ItemsControl к которому биндится ObservableCollection. В коллекции к примеру есть Name, Path и isChecked. Как можно сделать, если CheckBox isChecked == true выводилось общее количество файлов в папке (выбранных isChecked) и отображалось в TextBlock. Пробовал делать так:

```
private string _selectCountReg;
    public string SelectCountRegystry
    {
        get => _selectCountReg;
        set
        {
            _selectCountReg = value;
            OnPropertyChanget(nameof(SelectCountRegystry));
        }
    }

public ObservableCollection<GroupModel> groupModels { get; set; } //Коллекция биндится к ItemsControl

groupModels = new ObservableCollection<GroupModel>(GetInfo(получаем список файлов в папке));
                groupModels.CollectionChanged += GroupModels_CollectionChanged;

private void GroupModels_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.OldItems)
                item.PropertyChanged -= Update;
        }
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems)
                item.PropertyChanged += Update;
        }
    }

    public void Update(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectCountRegystry = groupModels.Count(x => x.IsChecked).ToString();
    }
```

XAML ItemsControl

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectCountRegystry, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding groupModels, IsAsync=True}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="{StaticResource BackgroundWhiteBrush}">

                <Grid>
                    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource MyCoolExpanderStyle}">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox
                                    Content="{Binding Name, Converter={local:ValueTextConverter}}"
                                    Foreground="{StaticResource CustomTextBrush}"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                            </StackPanel>
                        </Expander.Header>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Model

```
public class GroupModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DecreeModel> items { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

но ничего не отображается в TextBlock. Класс и модель реализует INPC. Скорее всего делаю не правильно. Подскажите.

Comment: `Класс и модель реализует INPC` - где? Я вижу `public string SelectCountRegystry { get; set; }`, без вызова `INPC`, вижу что вы этому свойству выдаете значение, оно меняется, но оповещать интерфейс кто будет?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, подправил. Никаких изменений нет.

Comment: Свойство то меняет свое значение на нужное?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, нет в TextBlock не выходит никого значения. Получается Update не срабатывает.

Comment: А в item INPC у свойства `isChecked` тоже нет?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, isChecked берется из модели. Модель тоже реализует INPC. Добавил модель

Comment: Как вы не поймете, что "реализация", это не только наследовать от класса. В INPC есть событие, вы на него подписались, `item.PropertyChanged += Update;`, ждете пока кто либо его вызовет, но кто это делать то будет? Где в свойстве `OnPropertyChanget()`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а разве не в SelectCountRegystry нужно вызвать OnPropertyChanget()?

Comment: Если вы хотите оповестить интерфейс об изменениях его значения, то да. Без его вызова свойство значение поменяет, но в интерфейсе останется старое, не обновленное значение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, так я и сделал, все равно ведь ничего не отображается.

Comment: Что вы сделали? Где у `public bool IsChecked { get; set; }` вызов события? Вот вы делаете подпись `item.PropertyChanged += Update;` на событие `PropertyChanged` у объекта `item`, этот объект я как понимаю `GroupModel`, где в этом классе хоть один вызов этого события?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, вы имеете ввиду в set SelectCountRegystry добавить Update. или нет? я не могу понять.

Comment: ... Какое у вас свойство должно измениться для вызова `Update`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, мне нужно чтобы при нажатии в Itemcontrol is Checked подсчитывалось кол-во файлов в папке и количество выводилось в SelectCountRegystry

Comment: Ну `is Checked`, это свойство оповещает о своем обновление (на которое вы подписались)?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, нет не оповещает

Comment: Ну вот, теперь понятно что надо сделать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, подскажи, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Да Семен Семеныч... Я же вам уже сказал, что не понятного в `Где у public bool IsChecked { get; set; } вызов события?` .. `Где в свойстве OnPropertyChanget()?`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, дааа... плохо чет доходит. Так это мне в модели добавить надо?

Comment: Вы каждый шаг будете спрашивать? Попробуйте сами, сюда как дополнения к вопросу прикрепляйте результаты.